# parametrize Hudson checkout path

Tags: svn, hudson

I am trying to figure out how to parametrize a hudson job so that i can checkout the code from different branch based on the parameter selected. I am able to use the parameter values in the shell script code, but not in checkout path(Repo URL).

Answer (score 0):

I do it by hand: I have trigger jobs that determine which branches need building (using [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin)). A trigger job then triggers several main build jobs passing them the branch name and revision as parameters. Those build jobs then use those parameters in order to update the appropriate branch (via shell build step) and build it. I use [BlameSubversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlameSubversion) in order to propagate changesets from trigger jobs to build jobs. Note, however, that I'm using Jenkins and not Hudson.